# Can squash commits and skip the step where I need to replace 'pick' with 'squash'?

Tags: git

I usually use the following command to squash commits after a certain commit :

```
git rebase - i <command hash I am not included in the squash>
```

However, this brings up a form where I need to replace `pick` with `squash` for all commits after the first one.

This gets tiresome whenever I am squashing a long list of commits, can I automate this step? (maybe there is an extra flag I am missing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create your commits with `git commit --squash SHA-OF-COMMIT-TO-SQUASH-TO` or `git commit --fixup SHA-OF-COMMIT-TO-FIXUP-TO` then you can use `git rebase -i --autosquash`.

Otherwise, using a find/replace in your editor will probably be the fastest way (i.e. in vim `2,$s/pick/squash`)

Comment: Did you mean `2,$s/pick/squash`?